# Make directory in private github repo public

Tags: git, github

I have a private repo on Github, *Repo A*. The structure of the project in Repo A is like:

```
dist/
src/
project-file.js
project-file2.js
```

**I want to make available the `src/` directory in a (new) public repo on Github.**

Ideally, I would like this to be as automatic as possible. So in the event that I update source files in Repo A, I would like the public repo to be easily updated, too.

I've found a couple of solutions: the first one involves using [Github releases and submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875559/share-publically-a-part-of-a-private-repo-on-github). This one seems to keep the two repos connected but I'm unsure how to push the `src/` directory into(?) the submodule and then push that to a fresh, public remote repository.

The other solution I found is [using `filter-branch` on a cloned repo](https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository). The only problem with using the latter that I can foresee is that the two branches then become detached and any changes I make to Repo A will have to be re-cloned again and pushed anew to the public repo.

Basically, I have a private project but I want to make some of the files public for viewing. I believe the first option, using submodules is the better choice, but I'm not sure how to do this in practice. I am not too well-versed with advanced Git techniques so apologies if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) remains a simpler option:

- first: [split your repository src folder into a new one](https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository)
- push that new repo to a new public GitHub empty repository
- add that repository as submodule in your current one:

That is:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/original/repo
git rm -r src/
git commit -m "Remove src"
git submodule add https://github.com/you/newSrcRepo src
```

From there, you can modify files in src and push to that new repo:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/original/repo
cd src
# work in src
git add .
git commit -m "new src modifications"
git push
```

And record the new src in your parent repo:

```
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "src new state"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gitexporter`](https://github.com/open-condo-software/gitexporter) CLI tool. It's a utility that processes all git commit-tree and creates a new git repo with the same commits but with only allowed files and directories.

**Example**

1. create `config.json`

```
{
    "forceReCreateRepo": true,
    "targetRepoPath": "my-open-source-repo-part",
    "sourceRepoPath": ".",
    "allowedPaths": ["src/*"],
    "ignoredPaths": [".env", "secret.json"]
}
```

2. run `gitexporter`

```
npx gitexporter config.json
```

3. publish your new public repo folder `my-open-source-repo-part`

You can also use this script in your CI and always have synced public repo.