# How to create public release from a private gitlab repo?

Tags: gitlab, release

I have a private repo and want to keep it private but would like to have a release that is publicly accessible. The [doc's](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/releases.html) doesn't give more hint's on it and it seems like that I would need to make the project itself public. Can someone confirm that?

Edit: It's not possible on github, without a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217941/can-i-make-releases-public-from-a-private-github-repo), probably same goes for gitlab.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible since GitLab 15.6. From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#publish-releases-without-giving-access-to-source-code):

> To make releases available publicly, set the following project settings:
>
> - Repository is enabled and set to Only Project Members
> - Releases is enabled and set to Everyone With Access

Answer (score 0):

I confirm my workaround for GitHub would need to be applied for a private GitLab repo:

- a separate public repo
- empty commits to which you can associate a release

The problem remains: a private repo is private for *all* its elements, including its releases.

The other approach would be to publish the releases in a public artifact repository (like [maven.org](https://search.maven.org/) for jars/wars for example): that depends on the nature of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this something people actually do? Or is this more of a last resort?

Comment: @user1767754 no, this is the current "best practice", as a practical solution.

Comment: Just trying to understand the details, so there will be still history on the `public` repo? I basically would like to apply your step's anytime we have a new release. Is there an example project on github that does your mentioned workaround?

Comment: @user1767754 No, the public repo is just there to record the releases, not to version any codebase history. You could version for instance a `RELEASE_NOTES.md` file each time you want to add a release to that public repo.

Comment: @user1767754 Note that GitLab 11.7 (this January) has introduced a full fledge Release feature: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/releases.html => https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/releases/index.html.