# Github releases - are they private for private repo?

Tags: github

I think this is a really stupid question but I can't find the answer.

I have a private repo on github. If I create a new release and "publish" it, does anything become public?

I want to keep it all private/internal and I'm not clear whether "release" means public release in any way.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, release assets on private repositories are private and require authentication to access or download.  This is useful if you have an internal tool that you'd like to provide binaries for, but don't want to share with everyone else.

Comment: On the other hand, you may want to do the opposite for some repos. Keep source code internal while making binaries public. This GitHub Actions [workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283567/7991646) (and others on the same thread) should perform that migration.