# Is it possible to do a private release from public repository in github?

Tags: github, release, public, repo

I have a public github repo, I want to release some of my changes but don't want to make them public. Can anyone let me know Is it possible to do a private release from a public repository?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't make release as private, but we can use the `pre-release` option provided by github. Something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to make a release, and you do not have an enterprise or subscription with Github, you will have to make the repo public. Another option, although less efficient will be to make a copy of the repo public with less info than the original one. That's why I said less efficient.

Comment: Or else once the release is done, can I make it private?

Comment: yes, when the release is done, you can return the repo to private. But mind you, you will lose any releases made. when it was public.

Comment: I can't make repo private, but is it possible to make already released tag private?

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere in github docs like we can't make a private release from public repo? As when I saw the doc (https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository) I am not able to find anything like this.

Comment: If you do try a 2-repo solution, these GitHub Actions workflows can handle migrating releases between them. Migrate [all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283567/7991646) releases. Migrate [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73169523/7991646) releases. The dev on the first link has been very responsive and could likely add more filtering options to help narrow down which releases get migrated.