# Public access to releases of a private GitHub repository

Tags: github

I have a private GitHub repository.

GitHub allows to create releases and publish them, including binaries (e.g. .msi).

However I don't know how to (and this is my question):

1. Give public access to the releases, even though the repo is private
2. Only the binaries (.msi) should be publicly accessible and not the source code zip (added to the releases by default)

In other words, I want everyone to be able to download and install the application, maintaining private the sources.

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/26217941/488287 for something similar to your question.

Comment: best I've found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217941/can-i-make-releases-public-from-a-private-github-repo

Comment: New answer on the same thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283567/7991646. When I tested the workflow, binaries were migrated without source code zip files. You can confirm that by downloading the placeholder zip files from migrated releases in the destination repo. They should not contain anything from the source repo.